# How to control the TextView text size through a SeekBar where the TextView is displayed in a ViewPager?

Tags: android

I want to control the size of the `TextView` with the help of a `SeekBar` i.e the `TextView` size increases when the `SeekBar` is dragged towards right and decreases while dragging towards left.I can do it when the `TextView` is displayed in a simple activity UI.But here the problem is the `TextView` have to be displayed inside a `ViewPager`.Please help me.

Following is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    TextView tv;
    SeekBar seek;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        /** Getting a reference to the ViewPager defined the layout file */
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        /** Getting fragment manager */
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter */
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

        /** Constructor of the class */
        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("current_page", arg0 + 1);
            myFragment.setArguments(data);
            return myFragment;
        }

        /** Returns the number of pages */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page #" + (position + 1);
        }

    }

    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        MainActivity m;
        int mCurrentPage;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
            Bundle data = getArguments();

            /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
            mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,
                    false);
            tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

            tv.setText("You are viewing the page #" + mCurrentPage + "\n\n"
                    + "Swipe Horizontally left / right");
            return tv;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `SeekBar` is outside the `ViewPager`. First set a `OnSeekBarChangeListener` on the `SeekBar`:

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {         
        if (fromUser) {
            MyFragment mf = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mCurrentItem);
            if (mf != null && mf.getView() != null) {
                mf.updateText(progress);
            }
            mf = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mCurrentItem - 1);
            if (mf != null && mf.getView != null) {
                mf.updateText(progress);
            }        
            mf = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mCurrentItem + 1);
            if (mf != null && mf.getView != null) {
                mf.updateText(progress);
            }        
        }
    }
};
```

where `mCurrentItem` is an `int` field which will store the current page of the `ViewPager`:

```
private int mCurrentItem = 0;
// ... in the onCreate method
seek.setMax(100); // the maximum for the TextView size
seek.setProgress(50); // the starting textSize for the TextView
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mListener);
```

You'll also need a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` on the `ViewPager` to update the `mCurrentItem` field:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mCurrentItem = position;
            MyFragment mf = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + position);
            if (mf != null && mf.getView() != null) {
                mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
                mSeekBar.setProgress((int) (mf.getTextSize()));
                mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mListener);
            }
        }
                    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to add this methods to your fragment class:

```
public void updateText(int progress) {
    textSize = progress;       
        ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.the_textview_id)).setTextSize(textSize);         
}
```

and

```
public float getTextSize() {
   return textSize;
}
```

where `mTextsize` is a field in your fragment's class which will hold the text size:

```
private float textSize = 50;
```

Just realized I may misunderstood the question. If you want to update the `TextView` size, its width/height, then instead of setting the text like in my answer, simply retrieve the `LayoutParams` from the `TextView` and update as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much Luksprog.Its working like a miracle.Just one more help plz..where I need to place this mTextSize in my code?

Comment: @Raam It was a small typo, `mTextSize` is in fact `textSize` which should be a field in your fragment class. I've edited the answer.

Comment: :Thanks again LuksProg.Everything is ok here but one problem is in each page I have to use the seekbar to inrease the text size.

Comment: @Raam Well, this is what I understood from your question that you want to do(the `SeekBar` updating the text for each fragmtns, individually). If you want the `SeekBar` to update the text from all the fragments, no matter at what page you are at, then make the `textSize` field from your `MyFragment` class as `static`  and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.Everything works fine here except it does not make changes to the immediate next page but works for the rest pages and also the app crashes when orientation changes.

Comment: @Raam I've edited my answer, check the `onProgressChanged` method. I don't know why the app crashes on orientation changing, you should start a new question and put there your code and the stacktrace with the exception.

Comment: is it possible to write mCurrentItem - 1 as mCurrentItem=0 as declared ?

Comment: I used the snippet of onProgressChanged() that you have earlier mentioned in MyFragment class and it works as per my need.I really appreciated the way you are replying.Thank you so much sir.